# Group by bucket (with NULL values)

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ransack

I have the following tables:

1. entries (id, title, text, duplicate_bucket_id)
2. duplicate_buckets (id, comment)

So every entry can be in a duplicate bucket. Now I want to get all entries without the duplicates:

```
SELECT MIN(id) FROM entries GROUP BY duplicate_bucket_id
```

The problem with this query is that it also groups all the entries without a duplicate_bucket_id to only one entry with NULL.

So I need something like this

```
(SELECT MIN(id) FROM entries WHERE duplicate_bucket_id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY duplicate_bucket_id)
UNION
(SELECT id FROM entries WHERE duplicate_bucket_id IS NULL)
```

This query gives me the correct result, but ActiveRecord can't use UNIONs.

Alternatively, I can use this query with a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM entries WHERE duplicate_bucket_id IS NULL OR id IN 
 (SELECT MIN(id) FROM entries WHERE duplicate_bucket_id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY duplicate_bucket_id )
```

In this query, I must place additional where-clauses in AND outside of the subquery. So the query gets quite complicated and I don't know yet, how to use the Ransack Gem with such a query...

The query would be simple, if every "entry" would be in a "duplicate_bucket" - buckets of size 1 (I could use *SELECT * FROM entries GROUP BY duplicate_bucket_id*). But I want to avoid to have entries in a duplicate_bucket, if the entry don't have a duplicate. Is there a simple query (no unions, no subqueries) to get all entries without their duplicates?

### Dataset

**entries(id, title, text, duplicate_bucket_id)**

```
1, 'My title', 'Bla bla', 1
2, 'Hello', 'Jaha', 1
3, 'Test', 'Bla bla', 1
4, 'Foo', 'Bla', NULL
5, 'Bar1', '', 2
6, 'Bar2', '', 2
```

**duplicate_buckets (id, comment)**

```
1, 'This bucket has 3 entries'
2, 'Bar1 and Bar2 are duplicates!'
```

### Result

```
1, 'My title', 'Bla bla', 1
4, 'Foo', 'Bla', NULL
5, 'Bar1', '', 2
```

Comment: Using `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY` simply does not make sense.  All columns in the `SELECT` for a `GROUP BY` should either be in the `GROUP BY` or arguments to aggregation functions.  You should edit your question to include sample data and desired results.

Comment: show a proper data sample and expected result

Comment: The data sample is added and the "SELECT * " problem is corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANSI/ISO SQL:

```
select      * 
from        entries as e1
where       not exists (select null from entries as e2 where e2.duplicate_bucket_id = e1.duplicate_bucket_id and e2.id < e1.id)
;
```

MySQL Terrible, Horrible, No Good, Very Bad syntax

```
select      * 
from        entries 
group by    coalesce(-duplicate_bucket_id,id)
;
```

Comment: Thank you. The MySQL example won't work if the entries#ids overlaps the duplicate_buckets#ids. I've "solved" it with GROUP BY coalesce(IF(ISNULL(duplicate_bucket_id),NULL,CONCAT('b:',duplicate_bucket_id)), IF(ISNULL(id),NULL,CONCAT('i:',id))) The syntax won't get better.. ;)

Comment: Yes.. So -NULL is NULL.. Wow!